# Handling POST using Warp/WAI

Tags: haskell, haskell-warp

How do you retrieve data from a POST request using `Network.Wai` and `Warp`?

Say for example, I have a simple webpage

```
....
<form method="POST" action="/handlepost">
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
....
```

When the user clicks submit, how can I retrieve this data? I know how to get GET data (`queryString`)

for example

```
app :: Application
app request = case rawPathInfo request of
                   "/" -> return $ displayForm
                   "/handlePost" -> return $ handlepost
                   _ -> return $ notFound

displayForm :: Response
displayForm = ResponseBuilder
    status200
    [("Content-Type", "text/html")] $
    fromByteString "<form method='POST' action='/handlepost'><input name="name" type="text" /><input type='submit'></form>"

handlePost :: Request -> Response
handlePost req = undefined -- how do I examine the contents of POST?
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to add to hammar's answer: the wai package itself just defines the interface, it doesn't provide any helper functions. What you're looking for is the `wai-extra` package, in particular [`parseRequestBody`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/wai-extra/0.4.2/doc/html/Network-Wai-Parse.html#v:parseRequestBody). Note that this allows you to control exactly how the uploaded files are stored, such as in temporary files or in memory.

Comment: Also http://langnostic.blogspot.de/2013/04/simple-web-chat-using-haskells-waiwarp.html provides a great example on how `parseRequestBody` can be used. The `wai-extra` documentation is a little cumbersome when it comes to setting the argument of type `Sink x y` right.

Answer (score 8):

WAI is quite a low level interface, so POST data is left unprocessed in the request body, just as it was received. You should be able to grab it using the `requestBody` function.

Of course, you will then have to parse it, as it's typically encoded in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format (or `multipart/form-data` for a form with file upload).  I suspect there might be helper functions for this somewhere, but I could not find any in the WAI package itself, at least.